# How to open flutter web app in browser just like a html file

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I was trying out flutter web and I wanted to share what I built with my friend so I wanted to know how to make my flutter web app open and run in browser just like html file where you would just click the file and open it with chrome and the site loads up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant open a flutter web project directly.

This is because `flutter build web`, will produce a Single Page App or `SPA` that will not work unless it's hosted via a server.

The user will either have to run a local server in-order to view the pages and for that you can use python 3's `http.serve` command or the `dart` variant `dhttpd`, the option is you can use a hosting solution like `firebase` or `netlify` to host your application if a local server is not possible.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer also is there any articles that I could follow that shows how to use local server and run the flutter web app

Comment: I use dhttpd docs available at https://pub.dev/packages/dhttpd, for firebase you can check https://levelup.gitconnected.com/build-a-web-app-with-flutter-and-deploy-it-to-firebase-hosting-3ee020b0e3db